# Why having getchar() assigned to a variable in a while loop condition leads to output of 0?

Tags: c

So currently I'm learning C from the C programming language 2nd edition book and it says that:

```
while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
}
```

is identical to:

```
while (c != EOF) {
   c = getchar();
}
```

However, when I run the code I just had written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int times;
    
    while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
        if (c == 'a') {
            ++times;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", times);
}
```

The value of `times` it outputs is 0 instead of actual value of times I typed in 'a' character.
Now in this code, it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int times;
    
    while (c != EOF) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 'a') {
            ++times;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",times);
}
```

and if I type `a` 3 times, the value it outputs is `3`.

Comment: Was the book expecting `c` to be of type `char`? Remember, `getchar` returns an `int`.

Comment: `times` is uninitialized, incrementing it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `c` is also uninitialized in the second version on the first time the `while` condition is checked.

Comment: Where does *The C Programming Lanuage* second edition say this? On page 51, it mentions assignment expressions can be used in expressions and uses `(c = getchar()) != EOF` as an example, and on page 153 it shows that while loop with correct parentheses, but I do not see where it shows that while loop with parentheses missing as it is shown in the question. What page did you copy this from? If the parentheses were in the book and you removed them, then you should remember that computers are mechanical and being precise matters. Source code from books should be reproduced exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precedence!

```c
c = getchar() != EOF
```

means

```c
c = ( getchar() != EOF )   // Assigns `0` or `1` to `c`.
```

but you want

```c
( c = getchar() ) != EOF
```

Also note that `c` needs to be an `int`.

---

This means you could use

```c
for (int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF; ) {
   ...
}
```

but I prefer

```c
while (1) {
   int c = getchar();
   if (c == EOF)
      break;

   ...
}
```

Comment: You should insist on the other mistake: `char c;` must be `int c;` for proper `EOF` testing.

Comment: @chqrlie I didn't go into much detail, but I did mention it

Answer (score 1):

**Operator precedence.**
!= operator is higher in precedence than =, so your expression is equivalent to:

```
 while (c = (getchar() != EOF))
```

use a parenthesis around c=getchar() and it will work.